# Removing global content language declaration from Composite C1

Tags: c1-cms

I have a client that wants his site to be fully valid HTML 5 mark up per the markup validation service at http://validator.w3.org/ There is only one little error that I think he can live with but I'd like to clear up if possible. Does anyone know how to remove the meta element that sets the global language e.g. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />` from the header markup in Composite C1? I have been unsuccessful locating it.

Comment: You only have to wait two days before answering your own question. It will be more understandable to separate the answer from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Content-Language meta tag is emitted from the Composite.Web.Html.Template.CommonMetaTags function and is indeed not html5.

You can fix this by removing the function call (the `<f:function name="Composite.Web.Html.Template.CommonMetaTags" />` from your layout template). This will also remove other meta tags and you can insert them instead if you like.

The other meta tags are these:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Composite C1 CMS - Free Open Source from http://composite.net/" />
```

Thanks to your post here this has been registered as a bug with Composite C1 and should be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the function Composite.Web.Html.Template.CommonMetaTags. I am still to new to figure out how to change the function itself, but as a workaround I just took the tags it extruded minus the content language and